# Where does user data is stored for Microsoft edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge, windows-10-v1703

I accidentally opened an url that keep Microsoft Edge crashing.
The problem is Microsoft Edge restore previous tabs by default if it was closed incorrectly, so it crash before I can click on anything.

So the only option is to delete Microsoft Edge user data files in order to get previous tabs “forgotten” since I can’t do it from the browser.

Comment: @Xavierjazz : as I told in the title, I need to know where I can delete my tabs data from the file explorer…

Comment: File Explorer != Microsoft Edge.  What you plan to do will have ZERO effect on File Explorer

Comment: @Ramhound : you mistunderstood, my browser session with my tabs history must be stored in some files… I want to know where those files are stored in order to delete them.

Comment: [Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/237527/how-to-reset-Microsoft-edge-in-Windows-10/) is how you reset Edge

Comment: @Ramhound I d like to keep fovorites.

Comment: So backup your [Favorite folder](https://techjourney.net/ms-edge-browser-favorites-storage-folder-location-for-export-save-backup/)

Comment: @Ramhound i dont where it is. your link explain how to delete all data with a powershell command.

Comment: My second link explains where your Edge favorites are stored

Comment: @Ramhound : but given my build version, I think https://techjourney.net/change-microsoft-edge-favorites-storage-location-disable-enable-ese-database/ is more relevant.

Comment: You should always provide information about build versions in the body of your question instead of just using a tag